# Host java Application on AWS

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, windows, amazon-web-services

I have 2 projects.

1. `Spring Restful Webservice`
2. `AngularJS`

Database is MySQL.

i am new to `AWS`, I want to host my application using AWS. So i want to `deploy` these projects on `AWS`.

When i create `MySQL` database on `AWS`, then what will be the `DB_URL` then i can use it on my java application.
When i deploy the WAR file on `AWS`, then what will be the URL then i can use it on my `AngularJS` application

Comment: You can go with Amazon RDS for MYSQL or Dynamo db local alone so that your end point would be localhost

Comment: thank you, what about WAR and AngularJS ?

Comment: to deploy a WAR,EAR with angular js I would suggest to go with HEROKU which is free tier .If you want to go with  AWS only then try with AWS lambda because they start charging after certain transaction.Read documentation for free-tier

Comment: HEROKU supports RDBMS ?

Comment: No I think it supports NoSQL database

Comment: can you please then me what will be the better HEROKU  or AWS on the basis of technology and security ?

Comment: If you want to go with high security without considering cost then I would suggest AWS but if you are  bothered about cost then HEROKU is fine.Even Heroku also gives good security features but compared to AWS ,it has some vulnerabilities .If you are doing any POC then go with Heroku instead of spending money on AWS

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155226/discussion-between-pradeep-and-sangram-badi).

Answer (score 1):

- **Database**: use RDS Mysql. After create, go detail of RDS instance you will get RDS Endpoint with this pattern: `RDS_INSTANCE_NAME.XXXXXXXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com` and default port 3306. You can access this RDS with that endpoint and user/pass as the local database (Import/export, Create schema,...) 
  About the web layer, you can create 2 EC2 instances: 1 for Web-service, 1 for AngrulaJS or create 1 EC2 instance and deploy both of them into that EC2 instance.

  You need SSH key to access via ssh. Then install your web container into EC2 instances and deploy as local server
- **AngrulaJS web**: There are many ways to public your app:

  1. you can use **Route53** to create A Record point to public IP of EC2 instance (Containt AngrularJS app)
  2. Use **Internet-facing ELB** point to EC2 instance.
  3. Use public IP that associated to EC2 instance.

I found a clearly architect design in this, you can reference it https://creately.com/diagram/example/h4gr4x8d4/3-Tier%20Architecture

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the application in EC2.

You have Public DNS (IPv4) value for Ec2 ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. You will use this endpoint for WAR file.

If you do not **assign Elastic ip for the EC2 Instance** when you stop and start instance the ip address changed for Instance.

Based on your requirements you can leverage other services like Load Balancer and Route53.

Comment: can you please tell me setp by step

Comment: did you copied you war file into EC2?